# Android приложение перестало отправлять почту

Tags: java, android, email

Пару дней назад прекрасно отправляло электронную почту через smtp, а сейчас отказывается и выдает ошибку:

```
    javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
```

почту отправляю на yandex

Вот код класса отправки письма:

```
public class GMail {

final String emailPort = "587";// gmail's smtp port
final String smtpAuth = "true";
final String starttls = "true";
final String emailHost = "smtp.yandex.ru";


String fromEmail;
String fromPassword;
List<String> toEmailList;
String emailSubject;
String emailBody;

Properties emailProperties;
Session mailSession;
MimeMessage emailMessage;

public GMail() {

}

public GMail(String fromEmail, String fromPassword,
             List<String> toEmailList, String emailSubject, String emailBody) {
    this.fromEmail = fromEmail;
    this.fromPassword = fromPassword;
    this.toEmailList = toEmailList;
    this.emailSubject = emailSubject;
    this.emailBody = emailBody;

    emailProperties = System.getProperties();
    emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.port", emailPort);
    emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", smtpAuth);
    emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", starttls);
    Log.i("GMail", "Mail server properties set.");
}

public MimeMessage createEmailMessage() throws AddressException,
        MessagingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {

    mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(emailProperties, null);
    emailMessage = new MimeMessage(mailSession);

    emailMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress());
    for (String toEmail : toEmailList) {
        Log.i("GMail", "toEmail: " + toEmail);
        emailMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                new InternetAddress(toEmail));
    }

    emailMessage.setSubject(emailSubject);
    //emailMessage.setContent(emailBody, "text/html");// for a html email
     emailMessage.setText(emailBody);// for a text email
    Log.i("GMail", "Email Message created.");
    return emailMessage;
}

public void sendEmail() throws AddressException, MessagingException {

    Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtp");
    transport.connect(emailHost, fromEmail, fromPassword);
    Log.i("GMail", "allrecipients: " + emailMessage.getAllRecipients());
    transport.sendMessage(emailMessage, emailMessage.getAllRecipients());
    transport.close();
    Log.i("GMail", "Email sent successfully.");
}
```

}

Comment: `AuthenticationFailedException` вам о чем то говорит ?

Comment: О том, что не проходит аутентификация. Но пароль и логин от почты подходят, я проверял

Comment: Возможно требуется дополнительная авторизация. Например гугл в таком сценарии требует чтобы в первый раз в браузере залогинились с девайса, с которого идёт попытка залогиниться в почте.программно.

Comment: для проверки, кто виноват я бы на вашем месте взял гмайл или другую почтовую программу, и попробовал бы в них указать логин и пароль, если заработает сразу, значит у яндекса что-то поменялось и надо править код, если не заработает, то искать как правильно подключиться. может они там скажем 25й порт перенесли для клиентов на 587, например.

Comment: @Yakov изменил почту на другую, вылетает новая ошибка : "    com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 501 5.1.7 Bad address mailbox syntax." Ошибка появляется новая если я изменяю IMAP на POP3

Comment: https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/issues/421

Comment: может у тебя неправильно заполняется получать? или логин не в том формате? ты пробовал через клиента gmail почта отправляется с телефона?

Comment: @Yakov надо было создать пароли приложений в настройках яндекс. И заходить на почту через этот пароль приложений, а не через обыкновенный. Только что попробовал отправить с телефона почту, она пришла.

Comment: Одна проблема с аутентификацией прошла, но пришла другая - теперь не отправляется сообщение. Вылетает такая ошибка: "com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 501 5.1.7 Bad address mailbox syntax." в гугле порылся, но так ничего и не нашел

Comment: @Yakov Да, я видел эту ссылку - "https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/issues/421" но я не особо понимаю куда вставлять "from"

Comment: думаю вместо emailMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress()); думаю должно выглядеть как emailMessage.setFrom(fromEmail);

Comment: @Yakov проверил - требует именно тип Address

Comment: https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=javax.mail.Message&method=setFrom

Comment: message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromEmail));

Comment: скорее всего почтовому серверу не нравится пустое поле отправителя, и он вас не пропускает

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.html

Comment: @Yakov спасибо! "message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromEmail));"это очень помогло! проблема решена! Огромное спасибо!